# What happens when 2 consumers in the same group wanted to read from the same topic if auto-commit is false

Tags: apache-kafka

**Topic**: mytopic

**Consumers**: C1 and C2, both have the same groupId(group1).

Let's assume `enable.auto.commit=false`.

C1 wants to poll from `mytopic` and reads the message with the `Offset 10` (remember that C1 does not commit the message because auto-commit is disabled).

What happens if C2 wants to poll from `mytopic`?

Does C2 get the message with `Offset 11` or wait for C1 to commit the message with the `Offset 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're only asking about one partition, then C2 will be idle until C1 is paused or stops heartbeating

You could always test out various scenarios to verify which offset would be returned for which consumer, but the answer actually depends on `auto.offset.reset`; if you've committed nothing to a group, and start a new consumer in that empty group, you'll end up at the earliest offset, the latest offset (not the latest read, as you'd need to commit that information), or no offset along with an error

Otherwise, you would need to seek the consumer to an offset that you want to read from